# Slow write on file after Spring Boot 3/Spring Batch 5 and JDK17 update

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, java-17

I have a Spring batch application with a custom writer step that writes a big amount of entities on file. Before the update to Spring Boot 3/Spring Batch 5 this step was fast but now, after the update, it became incredibly slow.

This is the writer method

```
    @Override
    protected String doWrite(Chunk<? extends List<ExportData>> chunk) {
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();

        List<ExportData> list = chunk.getItems().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (ExportData item : list) {
            lines.append(this.lineAggregator.aggregate(item)).append(this.lineSeparator);
        }
        return lines.toString();
    }
```

Do you have any ideas on what could cause this problem or what can I do to find out?

Comment: Is the app exactly the same in terms of job repository configuration, transaction manager configuration,etc? Also, please elaborate on what you mean by fast and slow, can you share numbers? For this kind of issues, we really need a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on Boot 2.7 that we can upgrade to Boot 3 and see the performance degradation to validate the point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually, investigating more deeply, the problem is reading from the DB. In particular we have a `this.repository.findByXAndY(...)` which loads a lot of data. This for some reason spikes the CPU of the machine (but not the RAM or DB CPU) to 100% causing a huge slowdown. Instead, if we load less data, everything works at the right speed. Probably something has changed in hibernate that no longer allows loading a large number of entities into memory, which was possible with spring boot 2.7.

Comment: Great to hear you solved your issue! In that case, please add an answer and explain the cause and how you solved the issue. This could be beneficial for other people that might have the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: I mean, I didn't really "solve" the issue, since before, with spring boot 2.7, I could load more entities in memory. We just did a workaround by loading less entities, but that's really case-specific, not a solution imho